# ¿Como eliminar un registro en especifico? Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas con las siguientes estructuras:

**Tabla: fotos,**

id_fot int(11) not null auto_increment (llave primaria)

usuario varchar(200)

ruta varchar(200)

descripcion varchar(200)

**Tabla: usuarios,**

id int(11) not null auto_increment (llave primaria)

usuario varchar(100) not null

nombre varchar(100) not null

email varchar(100) not null

contrasena varchar(100) not null

**MI PROBLEMA ESTA EN QUE AL SELECCIONAR EL ICONO DE ELIMINAR ME ELIMINA PERO EL PRIMER REGISTRO NO EL QUE YO SELECCIONO, SI QUIERO ELIMINAR POR EJEMPLO LA IMAGEN 3, SE ELIMINA LA 1, NO SE COMO ELIMINAR SOLAMENTE LA IMAGEN QUE EL USUARIO SELECCIONE(EN ESTE CASO EL REGISTRO)**

Esta es galeria.php.

```
<?php
session_start();
require'funcs/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}

?>

<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/personalizar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<?php
$use = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$use'";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<?php

require 'funcs/conexion.php';

$us = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_usuario']); 

$fo = "SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE usuario = '$us'";
$res = $mysqli->query($fo);

?>

<table class="table table-sm table-dark">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                        <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>

                    </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($ro = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <tr>

                <td><img src="<?php echo utf8_encode($ro['ruta']); ?>" width='200' height='200' 'image-align:center' /></td>
                <td><?php echo $ro['descripcion']; ?></td>
            <td><a href = "#" data-href = "borra.php?id_usuario=<?php echo $ro['usuario']; ?>" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#confirm-delete"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>                 

        </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
        </table>

  <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    ¿Desea eliminar este registro?
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>   

</body>
```

Este es el borra.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
require'funcs/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}

$us = $_GET['id_usuario'];

$sele = "SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE usuario = '$us'";
$res = $mysqli->query($sele);
$muestra = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$des = $muestra['id_fot'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM fotos WHERE id_fot = '$des'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

?>

<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
            <?php if($resultado)  { unlink($muestra['ruta']);header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria.php?id_usuario=".$_SESSION['id_usuario']);
  ?>

 <h3>REGISTRO ELIMINADO</h3>
            <?php } else {  header("Refresh: 0.5; galeria.php?id_usuario=".$_SESSION['id_usuario']); ?>
            <h3>ERROR AL ELIMINAR</h3>
            <?php } ?>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que el problema esta aquí:

```
$sele = "SELECT * FROM fotos WHERE usuario = '$us'";
$res = $mysqli->query($sele);
$muestra = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$des = $muestra['id_fot'];
```

`$des` siempre obtendrá el primer valor de `fotos` para el usuario `$us` pues no hay manera de conocer que elección hizo el usuario. ¿Has probado enviar directamente el `id_fot` directamente desde `galeria.php`? Así podrías eliminarlo directamente sin hacer este paso extra.

Valdría la pena que vieras como evitar la inyección SQL pues tu código es vulnerable, aun si esto es un proyecto te vendría bien. [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/108071)

Comment: gracias amigo, así lo resolví. saludos.